# How to capture the consolidate the output of files into one file, and append any new information?

Tags: bash

Currently I have this to grab the output of many individual files and consolidate them into a single logfile.
However is it possible when I run this in the future to only append new data, instead of re-writing it?
I'm not sure if I should be using `>>` or not..

```
find /var/log/2015 -type f -exec cat {} \; > /var/log/logfile
```

Right now I have a `cron` job running every second (`* * * * *`) to update but I'm not sure if this is good practice or not.

Comment: If you don't throw away/move the files that you process, they will be seen the next time the find is run again. You can use '>>' but you also need to move files found to some other place (not under /var/log/2015) or remove them after `cat`-ing them

Comment: If you have only one directory level, i.e. there's no subdirectory in `/var/log/2015` then a better form is `cat /var/log/2015/*` if name sort is enough (find may happen to list items somehow randomly). Other questions are: a) is the number of files under `2015` going to grow? b) are subdirectories allowed under `2015`? In the worst case, `find` might take too long or at least more than one second to process files, depending on the total number of lines and search depth.

Comment: a) No, I have a monthly archiving system which creates an archive and deletes the individual logs
b) Yes, there are many subdirectories based on the date i.e. 2015/02/03/router..
The problem is that LogAnalyzer (a GUI interface for rsyslog) only takes in a flat file, so this is the only solution I can think of at the moment.
@Christa okay makes sense, thank you.

Comment: So you are just appending each log file to a master log.  You are not attempting to do date sort of a new file grouping before appending the latest sorted file to the earlier already sorted master log. Correct? As Christa suggested, to avoid the automated processes handling logs under /var/log, I always keep process-related logs in a segregated process-specific directory.  That keeps it clean.  You can keep all those directories under one top-level directory called /LOGS_local, or /Local/logs.  It really depends on your need for ease of access or need to keep such admin together.